# offsetTop property on element with display: none is always 0

Tags: javascript, css

I suspect this is the correct behavior but I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to get the actual value of the offsetTop of the element.

The desired behavior is when a user clicks a button the list will be scrolled so that the selected item will be the at the top, this works fine while the element is visible, but it can be hidden and we would like this behavior to happen even when it's hidden so when the user unhides it then the list is scrolled to the desired item.

html

```
<div id='list-wrapper'>
  <ul>
    <li id='one'>One</li>
    <li id='two'>Two</li>
    <li id='three'>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.list-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

JS

```
let listElement: Element = document.getElementById('list-wrapper');
let li3: Element = document.getElementById('three');
listElement.scrollTop = li3.offsetTop;
```

Comment: A way to work around it would be to cache the scroll operation until you show the element if the element is hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;` instead to hide the element as that will allow the element to still be on the page where it would normally, just visually hidden.

If you can't do that, you can switch the element to use `opacity` or `visibility` temporarily, just to get the `offsetTop` position - then switch it back to `display: none;`

Comment: Yeah I considered this and it would require a major refactor of how the workspace is positioned and how the sizes of other items are calculated to account for the fact that the element still takes up the same space in the document even when it's not visible.

Comment: @efarley you can do something like set the `height` and `width` to `0` until it's displayed.

Answer (score 0):

In compliance with the specification, this property will return null on Webkit if the element is hidden (the style.display of this element or any ancestor is "none") or if the style.position of the element itself is set to "fixed".

This property will return null on Internet Explorer (9) if the style.position of the element itself is set to "fixed". (Having display:none does not affect this browser.)

[from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)